# How to push one array to another during subscribe Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, infinite-scroll, angular2-components

How to pass value of array to another empty array during subscribe in Angular 2. I want to create infinite scroller in Angular 2. I have an array of 10 values. In infinite scroller, I want to repeat those 10 values again and again.
Below is the code in the component:

```
array =[];
eNews = [];
 getNewsList(){

          this._newsService.getData()
           .subscribe(resNewsData => this.eNews = resNewsData);

     }
```

I want to push eNews to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** operator over an array

```
 this.eNews = this.eNews.concat(resNewsData);
```

Comment: this._newsService.getData()
  .subscribe(resNewsData => this.eNews.concat(resNewsData));                            concat is not working during subscribe methods.                                            Outside subscribe eNews.length is zero so how can i get eNews?

Comment: you cannot access it outside since the getData is asynchronous , you can place it inside subscribe and pass to a function to count the length

Comment: I am getting  error;                                                                                       ViewWrappedError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in ./NewsComponent class NewsComponent

Comment: I want to call function additems :                                                                        addItems(startIndex, endIndex,_method) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sum; ++i) {
      this.eNews[push]([i,this.getNewsList()].join(''));
    }
  }                                                                                                                      want to repeat eNews array again and again because want to implement infinite scroller